# Maximum possible photo compression

Tags: image, image-processing, compression, image-compression

In a very resource constrained environment, I want to include images and photos.  Space is very constrained and directly determines the maximum number of images I can support.  So, I'd like to compress the images as much as possible.  I'm willing to sacrifice quality and aesthetics.  However, there comes a point where they're simply not recognizable.  At that point, it doesn't matter how many images I include!

What's a good compression scheme for this type of situation? JPEG with maximum compression? WebP? What params should I use? How much of an improvement over typical JPEGs (as found on the web) can I expect?

*UPDATE* To clarify, I'm not sending these anywhere.  There's no bandidth limitations - it's storing them in a homebrew, unusual, embedded microcontroller application.  I'd like to get images down to 1 or 2 KB.  Experimenting with WebP has made this possible for many, but by no means all, types of images.

JPEG isn't enough for this - I need more powerful compression algos (and JPEG has been outdated by far!)

Comment: jpgs are by definition compressed.  Most jpgs found on the web are already pretty tiny, only a few hundred K for the large ones (for reference, the GOOGLE logo on their homepage is around 14K).  How constrained are you?  If you're worried about sending 14K images, then you may have bigger problems.

Comment: Can you not experiment with e.g. GIMP to see what compression levels you can achieve? Load a test image and save it as jpg. Set the compression rate to e.g. 90% and see what the result is like. That should give you some clues as to whether jpg is right for you and what is achievable.

Comment: You could try changing to grayscale and using dithering to reduce the overall color set.

Comment: @kkuilla - See update that JPEG not sufficient